# AJAX jQuery new version about "Insert into database without page load"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm new to AJAX, I'm using old code:

```
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'phppath/sucms.php',
  data: $('#formid').serialize(),
  success: function(response){
   $('#success').html(response);
  }
 });
```

It works, but not perfectly, everything is good but when I try to upload an image it has "CLEAR VALUE".

I'm trying make new code like this:

```
  var formData = new FormData(this);
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'phppath/sucms.php',
  data: formData ,
  success: function(response){
   $('#success').html(response);
   }
  });
```

but it reloads the page and opens sucms.php clear window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to upload files using ajax, you need to set contentType and processData as false in your ajax config.

```
    var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append(<KEY>, <FILE>);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        url: 'phppath/sucms.php',
        data: formData ,
        success: function(response){
            $('#success').html(response);
        }
    });
```

On the other hand, if the page is being reload or opened in a new window. It is probably because the type of your button is `submit`. You should change the button type to `button` or use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the action being execute in the traditional form submit approach.

Comment: When i use this code, after dont upload in database, why i can't undestand........

Comment: 2 day i am have this problem

Comment: you need to append all data using formData.append(<KEY>, <VALUE>), only those data appended in the formData object can be used in server side script.